# Query string inside ASP.Net Core Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

How to output ampersand `&` as part of query string in razor view?

Let's say we have script element and some jquery code inside view:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '[?]',
    success: function (content) { $('body').append(content); },
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 30000
```

But we cannot use something like this `@Url.Content("~/my/custom/url?some=1&query=2")` as *url* because ampersand will be decorated...

Comment: Hi Maxim, I've done query strings in ASP.Net Core like this: <code> Url.Action("ControllerMethod", new { param1 = Model.value[0]. param2 = "value2" }) </code>    -- This will be converted to /ControllerMethod?param1=value1&param2=value2 . Do you need to do it in JQuery for some reason or will the Html helper method work?

Comment: Hi... something is missing ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it finally... It looks a bit tricky and not better than old classic ASP.Net.. but it works:

```
url: '@Url.Content($"~/my/custom/url")@Html.Raw($"?some=1&query=2")'
```

If you need to output some custom data as parameters in query string then consider HtmlEncode to avoid XSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it using Razor I've done Query strings in ASP.Net Core as like this:

```
@Url.Action("ControllerMethod", new { param1 = "value1". param2 = "value2" })
```

This will converted by ASP.Net into

```
/ControllerMethod?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will be converted to "param1=value1&amp;param2=value2;" and only in case if ControllerMethod route exists. So ampersand is still converted.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you are trying to do. Would you mind please posting you Controller method and relevant View code? The @Url.Action method I posted above is that standard way to do query strings to a controller method in ASP.Net Core and the ampersand does not get  encoded by default in any of my production code.

Comment: Url.Content or Url.Action decodes ampersand before output... It is not any specific case.. you code simply does not work... I need & not &amp;

Comment: My apologies on the code not working for you I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. You are trying to pass a query string to a MVC controller method yes? Could you please post your view code and controller code?

Comment: I want to avoid ampersand encoding as I wrote in my question... Look at my own answer.. I had to move query string into raw section.

Comment: Oh I understand now. You need to create the URL to embed it in JQuery/Ajax call. Thank you for clarifying.